# Setting ListViewItem property IsEnabled based on attribute of item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am trying to define the IsEnabled Property on each ListViewItem in the ListView based on the value of an attribute of the item itself. The xaml below will allow me to bind to a property of the page's datacontext, but not to one of the indiviual item being displayed.

```
<ListView Height="450" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" ItemClick="ItemSelected" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" FontFamily="Global User Interface">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MarkedOffNotRemoved}"></Setter>
         </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

With the property on the Item Type

```
    public Boolean MarkedOffNotRemoved
    {
        get
        {
            return MarkOff == null || !MarkOff.Removed;
        }
    }
```

With the code like this, the error I see is from ReSharper (Not VisualSTudio) and it is a "Cannot resolve property in the Data context" error. The error also indicates the context it is looking at is the ViewModel for the page, not the individual items. VisualStudio compiles the code without error, however the page does not behave as expected and when debugging the get for MarkedOffNotRemoved is not called at all.

Is there a way to change my binding to an attribute of each item in the collection such that the binding property will actually be called? Or will I need to use an ItemContainerStyleSelector along with a style for enabled items and a style for disabled items?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `ListView` works correctly. The control you're *actually* using in your app — probably not.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either: the datacontext of an item in your listview will be the element in the ItemsSource, not the page's datacontext. Show the binding you used (rather than XXXXX). Is the property you are trying to bind to a boolean? What errors do you get in the VS output? It will report binding errors and state what type of control it couldn't find an `IsEnabled` property on, if it is indeed having a binding error.